# Do a mouse wheel in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

Is there a way to send out mouse wheel events in protractor? I looked on the web but the only thing i could find was the scrollIntoView method. I really need to be able to invoke wheel events so i can test them.

Answer (score 3):

[There is no "mouse wheel" action](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#h-actions) specified by the selenium webdriver. You should use [`.scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo), [`.scrollBy()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy) and [`.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) through the [`browser.executeScript()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript) interface. There is also `mouseMove` relevant browser action, but that would effectively scroll into view of the element under the hood:

```
browser.actions.mouseMove(elm).perform();
```

Comment: But it seems `browser.actions.mouseMove(elm).perform();` will not trigger the `scroll` event. `.scrollIntoView()` works perfect.